# Any Js which can detect flash video lenght and show play again and next video

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, flash-video

I am wondering is there `Java Script` library or script or any trick which can detect flash video length and show play again and next video after its end.
As **YouTube** do.

any reference example or tutorial can also help me.

**I am here after Google.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is the flash video player to make an [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) call to javascript letting it know it has completed. You would need access to the flash file to accomplish this.

You could technically track the video play progress with javascript and load the next video on complet. The problem with this is that it would require you not only to know the length of the video, but also when it plays/stop. The only way to do that is by having flash make [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) calls. At that point, you might as well just listen for the video's complete event.